# Need xml bean's java representation in Spring4

Tags: java, spring-mvc, weblogic, jndi, spring-4

How can i represent the following code snippet in java, my project is using  Spring4 and i need to convert the same. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
  <property name="environment">
     <props>
        <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory</prop>
        <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">t3://localhost:7001</prop>
     </props>
  </property>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the equivalent Java config. Add it to your `@Configuration` class:

```
@Bean
public JndiTemplate jndiTemplate() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty(InitialContext.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
    props.setProperty(InitialContext.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:7001");
    return new JndiTemplate(props);
}
```